# The requested module 'react' is expected to be of type CommonJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm having this kind of error when I added this to my Next.js app

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Popover, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { MenuIcon, XIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
```

Node version is `14.6.0`
Next version is `12.1.0`

Here's the full error message:

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'react' is expected to be of type
> CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can
> be imported by importing the default export.

I've tried to just use this instead but no luck:

```
import React from 'react'
import Headless from '@headlessui/react'
import HeadlessOutline from '@heroicons/react/outline'
```

And use it like `React.Fragment` or `Headless.Transition`

Comment: You have a misconfigured tsconfig.json

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I'm not using typescript. I don't have tsconfig file.

Comment: So this must be a babel error

Comment: Can you tell me what might be wrong with the configurations?